# Correct way to parallelize work with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

There are many posts on SO asking specific questions about asyncio, but I cannot grasp the right way on what to use for a given situation.

Let's say I want to parse and crawl a number of web pages in parallel. I can do this in at least 3 different ways with asyncio:

with `pool.submit`:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
    result_futures = list(map(lambda x: pool.submit(my_func, x), my_list))
    for future in as_completed(result_futures):
        results.append(future.result())
return results
```

With `asyncio.gather`:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
     futures = [loop.run_in_executor(pool, my_func, x) for x in my_list]
     results = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
```

With just `pool.map`:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
     results = [x for x in pool.map(my_func, arg_list)]
```

`my_func` is something like

```
async def my_func(arg):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(...):
            ...
```

Could somebody help me understand what would be the differences between those 3 approaches? I understand that I can, for example, handle exceptions independently in the first one, but any other differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these. `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `run_in_executor` will all execute your code in another thread, no matter you use the asyncio loop to watch for their execution. And at that point you might just as well not use asyncio at all: the idea of async is exactly managing to run everything on a single thread - getting some CPU cycles and easing a lot on race-conditions that emerge on multi-threaded code.

If your `my_func` is using async correctly, all the way (it looks like it is, but the code is incomplete), you have to create an asyncio `Task` for each call to your "async defined" function. On that, maybe the shortest path is indeed using `asyncio.gather`:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp, ... # things used inside "my_func"

def my_func(x):
    ...

my_list = ...

results = asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(*(my_func(x) for x in my_list)))
```

An that is all there is for it.

Now going back to your code, and checking the differences:
your code work almost by chance, as in, you really just passed the async functiona and its parameters to the threadpool executor: on calling any async function in this way, they return imediatelly, with no work done. That means nothing (but some thin boiler plate inner code used to create the co-routines) is executed in your threadpool executors. The values returned by the call that runs in the target threads (i.e. the actual `my_func(x)` call) are the "co-routines": these are the objects that are to be awaited in the main thread and that will actually performe the network I/O. That is: your "my_func" is a "co-routine function" and when called it retoruns immediately with a "co-routine object". When the co-routine object is awaited the code inside "my_func" is actually executed.

Now, with that out of the way: in your first snippet you call `future.result` on the concurrent.futures Future: that will jsut give you the co-routine object: that code does not work - if you would write `results.append(await future.result())` then, yes, if there are no exceptions in the execution, it would work, but would make all the calls in sequence: "await" stops the execution of the current thread until the awaited object resolves, and since awaiting for the other results would happen in this same code, they will queue and be executed in order, with zero parallelism.

Your `pool.map` code does the same, and your `asyncio.gather` code is wrong in a different way: the `loop.run_in_executor` code will take your call and run it on another thread, and gives you an awaitable object which is suitable to be used with `gather`. However, awaiting on it will return you the "co-routine object", not the result of the HTTP call.

Your real options regarding getting the exceptions raised in the parallel code are either using `asyncio.gather`, `asyncio.wait` or `asyncio.as_completed`. Check the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I really appreciate it! Too bad it's possible to make the code work by chance...